# Flutter app on real devices requires the Google Play Store, but it is missing

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I have android device A505 Android 6.0.1. After install app and try call post api get below message in console.

```
W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(  662): com.example.attendance requires the Google Play Store, but it is missing.
```

**Note: Device don't have play store!**

On other device android 5 and android 11 work fine.

Answer (score 0):

install a virtual android phone with google play sore and the problem is solved.